# Do you know open source alternatives for UISplitViewController?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I think the fixed width of `RootViewController` in `UISplitViewController` is quite a limitation: for some cases 320px is way too much space to waste, while `DetailedView` could use more space efficiently to provide better UX. (a good example of "some cases" is Living Social iPad app)

So far I've found [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad). Do you know of any other open source solutions extending `UISplitViewController` functionality?

I know that using alternatives are a bit against "the HIG", but did you hear of any app using alternative solutions was rejected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cUISplitViewController](https://github.com/palaniraja/cUISplitViewController) is a Good one.

Comment: quite nice addition, maybe not feature-rich, but clean and tidy so it helps me understand how to write my own implementation. Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome. is this the answer or u still looking for more?

Comment: still looking for. If no one shows up with more interesting alternative, I'll accept your answer, don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another: [APSplitViewController](https://github.com/SlavaBushtruk/APSplitViewController)

And another: [IntelligentSplitViewController](https://github.com/grgcombs/IntelligentSplitViewController) (Dangerous in my opinion)

And FYI, using alternate solutions are not discouraged in any way by Apple's HIG. If the alternate solution is violating the HIG or other standard guidelines e.g. use of private APIs etc, then you'll face problems.

p.s. I'm looking for a solution that works like UISplitViewController, but with UITabBar. UISplitViewController, MGSplitViewController both provide excellent controls but they both don't work with UITabBar. IntelligentSplitViewController was/is the perfect candidate, but it accesses private members :^(.

Comment: I'm already using `MGSplitViewController` with some fixes from its forks and it works pretty well. You're right about the HIG approach/understanding. Thank you for your input :)

Comment: Are you using MGSplitViewController inside a UITabBar. If you are, i'm very interested to hear about it. I'm currently facing plenty of issues using it inside a UITabBar. The most critical is the one related to alignment. In my case the UITableViewCell content is misaligned on rotation. My UITableView is placed inside UINavigationController (Master view). I haven't found any solution to this problem in the Issues list. Have you seen or dealt with this problem?

Comment: since I don't use it inside a UITabBar, I don't see the problems you mention - for regular MGSplitViewController usage, everything is fine with orientation handling. I've also never came across UISplitView+UITabBar combination, so no idea what might be wrong. Good luck!

Comment: have you tried APSplitViewController? https://github.com/slatvick/APSplitViewController

Comment: Yes, i have :). Only problem is, it doesn't hide the master view in portrait view (like uisplitviewcontroller).

Comment: So far I've heard zero problems with getting apps approved using IntelligentSplitViewController, and many reports of success.  I've added a link to a rich demo/template that goes into more detail on implementation.  Also, I've just released my main application that uses this controller to GitHub, previously known as TexLege, now it's [StatesLege](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/stateslege).